# Why does creating a service in AWS ECS require the ecs:CreateService permission on all resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create a service on AWS ECS, using CloudFormation. The user trying to create service has a role granting it the `ecs:CreateService` permission on the cluster that will host the service. However, the service fails to create with this error message:

> User: (user ARN) is not authorized to perform: ecs:CreateService on resource: *

Why is this permission necessary, when I've specified the cluster I'm creating the service on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CreateService` API does not support resource-level permissions.  The APIs that support resource-level permissions are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-supported-iam-actions-resources.html).